# Grails on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: grails

I am installing Grails on Ubuntu 12.10, using the instructions [here](http://grails.org/download/ubuntu), but an getting an error on the 3rd step, as outlines below.

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails
- sudo apt-get update
- **sudo apt-get install grails-ppa**

The error I get is shown below.  I have the Sun JDK installed, and **JAVA_HOME** is set, and **JAVA_HOME/bin** is on the path.

Can someone suggest things to try to resolve this?

```
/home/edgecase> $ sudo apt-get install grails-ppa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre-headless:i386 : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386 (>= 7~u3-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-7-jre:i386 : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386 (= 7u7-2.3.2a-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.


/home/edgecase> $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_39"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to remove those instructions from the site since the PPA isn't being maintained. Use http://gvmtool.net/ instead.

Comment: I managed to get it working by uninstalling/re-installing all things Java.  But I used the original instructions.  Is what I installed still valid?

Comment: probably, but since it's no longer maintained you won't get new versions. Use GVM to get the latest, and to install multiple versions and switch between them as needed. It will also install other stuff like Groovy, Gradle, etc. if you need those separately.

Answer (score 0):

YES please remove the PPA instructions with GVM, I wasted a lot of time before I found this